# Why isn't Casper POS Dynasty set randomized?

Tags: proof-of-stake

This may be premature to ask this question as POS for ethereum is still undergoing a lot of design changes, but it seems like from all the stuff I've come across that the validator set (eg. dynasty) is told ahead of time the epoch which they are going to be preparing / committing to.  Why isn't a validator given a epoch at random because it seems that there could be a attack vector where a attacker is able to coordinator with other ones to join a specific epoch to compromise?